# DB User account Password Reset from oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Iam creating an app to change the password of selected Db user account.When an user select a particular db name and user of the db then click submit button i should call procedures that changes the password of the db user.So guide me how to connect to selected db from oracle Apex and do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to change someone's password:

- connect as that user
- connect as a privileged user (such a SYS)

and run such a command:

```
alter user scott identified by tiger;
```

As you'd want to do that for any database you have a access to, as well as every user in those databases, I doubt that you know their passwords so I guess that you'll connect as a privileged user to all those databases. Of course, you have to know *their* passwords.

One option would be to

- create the same stored procedure (which will modify someone's password) in every database

  - it'll accept username and its new password
  - as `alter table` is DDL, you'll have to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`)
- create database links to those databases in a schema you use to connect to your Apex application
- depending on database you choose, call appropriate procedure via database link and pass chosen username and its new password. This might also require some kind of dynamic SQL, if you want to use different DB link name

I don't know which database version you use, but - have a look at 11g's [Accessing and Modifying Information in Multiple Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_distdbs.htm#BABEFFBB), especially "Running a Stored Procedure in a Remote Oracle Database" chapter for more info.

Comment: Littlefoot thanks for you help. Is it possible to do by an shell script?

Comment: Can we run a unix script located in unix server path from oracle apex using Stored procedure.Required to change db password from Oracle Apex

Comment: You're welcome. Shell script? I guess you could use it, yes. You'd pass number of parameters to it (privileged as well as "target" user's credentials), and you'd have to have SQL*Plus installed as you have to *somehow* connect to the database. `alter user` would then be part of the .SQL script.

Comment: In order to call an operating system script from PL/SQL, use `dbms_scheduler` package; see documentation for more info.

Comment: Hi Little foot thanks . I need to change db password which is in unix server by executing a shell script. This script(located at unix db server) contains code to change the password.Then i need to run this script from oracle apex stored procedure.This oracle apex is windows server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202386/discussion-between-raghu-and-littlefoot).

Comment: I dont have access to this.Its blocked

Comment: HI Littlefoot dbms_scheduler to run unix script where wil we write connection details to unix server  in stored procedure .

Comment: Nowhere. Script has to be on the database server, so it is available to the stored procedure.

Comment: Need to create firt BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_credential(
       username => 'OS Username',
        password => 'OS password',
        credential_name => 'TEST_CREDENTIAL'
    );
END;